# a queer problem on repeated root

Tags: calculus, leibniz-integral-rule

if $f(x),g(x),h(x),\phi(x)$ are  distinct polynomials and let $$l(x)=\left(\int_{1}^{x}f(x)h(x)dx\right)\left(\int_{1}^{x}g(x)\phi(x)dx\right)-\left(\int_{1}^{x}f(x)\phi(x)dx\right)\left(\int_{1}^{x}g(x)h(x)dx\right)$$ is divisible by $(x-1)^a$ find $\max(a)$.($l(x)$ is not identically zero)

Answer given is $5$.

ofcourse  $l(1)=0$. Also i know that for repeated  root (in this case number of repetitions $5$) we can say
$$l(1),l'(1),l''(1).l'''(1),l''''(1)=0$$.i was able to prove $l'(1)=0$ but the more i differentiate the more ugly it gets.

I am sure there is a simple trick to solve this problem.can anyone provide a hint?thanks!!

Comment: @PrimeMover thanks for the edit

Comment: No worries, but haven't got a clue how to go about solving it. :-)

Comment: If all the polynomials are equal then $l(x)=0$, which is divisible by $(x-1)^a$ for all $a$.

Comment: @lulu  interesyting point i forgot to mention distinct

Comment: Doesn't help.  Say $g=2f, h=3f, \phi=4f$.  Then you still get $0$.

Comment: @lulu well  lets say  they are not mutiples

Comment: It's not good practice to just change the problem every time a counterexample is proposed.  Think through what you want to ask and try to find your own counterexamples (or a proof).

Comment: @lulu thank you I guess my altitude towards a problem has always been to jump to the proof rather than checking if it is correct. I will fix it .anyway could you elaborate more on how g=2f h=3f $\phi=4f$ results in 0.

Comment: Both terms in your sum are $4!\times \left(\int_1^x f(x)^2 dx\right)^2$

Comment: @lulu oh got it Then if possible  could you explain in  what pretext the  answer is $5$ the question may have been inteded to avoid special cases.

Comment: Well, one obvious guess is that the problem should read "show that either $l(x)=0$ identically, or  $a≤5$."  But I don't know if that's true or not.

Comment: yes that could be the case .

Comment: Try to find counterexamples!   Consider the case $f(x)=(x-1)^6, g(x)=(x-1)^7, h(x)=(x-1)^8, \phi(x)=(x-1)^9$ for example.  I think it is clear that in this case $l(x)$ is divisible by a high power of $(x-1)$ (actually, $(x-1)^{32}$ barring careless error).

Comment: As stated, I don't think the claim in the problem is even close to being true.

Comment: @lulu yes i agree with you ,i guess it is wrong .I have been sitting on this problem for 1 hour to realise it is wrong!!.

Comment: It's possible that there's an order-of-quantifiers problem here. Maybe it should say "find the largest value of $a$ such that $(x-1)^a$ *always* divides $\ell(x)$, no matter what the polynomials $f, g, h, \phi$ are." In that case, you'd at least expect $a$ to be bounded. Then again, maybe it's just botched up nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the problem is correctly stated. One that would make more sense would be to find **the maximal value of $a$ for fixed polynomials** (as there is no upper bound if you change the polynomials).

The answer will be highly dependent on the polynomials you chose, but we can still say something in general (namely we can get a lower bound) : instead of differentiating, you can reason with the multiplicity of 1 as a root in each term of your expression.

Let's denote $v_1(P)$ for the multiplicity of $1$ as a root of $P$; or equivalently, $v_1(P)$ is the biggest $a$ such that $(x-1)^a$ divides $P$. We take the convention $v_1(0) = +\infty$. Notice that for any polynomials $P$, $Q$, we have :

$$v_1(P Q) = v_1(P) + v_1(Q)$$

and

$$v_1(P + Q) \ge \min(v_1(P), v_1(Q))$$

with equality if $v_1(P) \ne v_1(Q)$. And finally,

$$v_1\left(\int_1^x P(t) dt\right) = v_1(P) + 1$$

since the derivative of $\int_1^x P(t) dt$ is $P$.

Now getting back to the problem : we can use the above properties to show

$$v_1\left(\int_1^x P_1 P_2 \int_1^x P_3 P_4 -  \int_1^x P_1 P_4 \int_1^x P_2 P_3 \right) \ge \min \left[v_1\left(\int_1^x P_1 P_2 \int_1^x P_3 P_4\right), v_1\left(\int_1^x P_1 P_4 \int_1^x P_2 P_3\right)\right]$$

and

$$v_1\left(\int_1^x P_1 P_2 \int_1^x P_3 P_4\right) = v_1\left(\int_1^x P_1 P_2 \right) + v_1\left(\int_1^x P_3 P_4\right) = (v_1(P_1 P_2) + 1) + (v_1(P_3 P_4) + 1)= v_1(P_1) + v_1(P_2) + v_1(P_3) + v_1(P_4) + 2$$

and similarly

$$ v_1\left(\int_1^x P_1 P_4 \int_1^x P_2 P_3\right) = v_1(P_1) + v_1(P_2) + v_1(P_3) + v_1(P_4) + 2$$

which gives finally

$$v_1\left(\int_1^x P_1 P_2 \int_1^x P_3 P_4 -  \int_1^x P_1 P_4 \int_1^x P_2 P_3 \right) \ge v_1(P_1) + v_1(P_2) + v_1(P_3) + v_1(P_4) + 2$$

To go any further, one would have to know the polynomials themselves ($v_1\left(\int_1^x P_1 P_2 \int_1^x P_3 P_4 -  \int_1^x P_1 P_4 \int_1^x P_2 P_3 \right)$ can get arbitrarily bigger than $v_1(P_1) + v_1(P_2) + v_1(P_3) + v_1(P_4) + 2$, it can even get infinite in some cases, as in the comments).